# not able to deploy application gateway using terraform as resource is taking too long to deploy

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-application-gateway

Hi I am trying to deploy the application gateway and it's taking lot of time to deploy. Its taking more than 28mins.

module.app-gateway.azurerm_application_gateway.agw: Still creating... [28m38s elapsed]
module.app-gateway.azurerm_application_gateway.agw: Still creating... [28m48s elapsed]

Here is the terraform code I am using

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "agw" {
  name                = "${var.env}-hub-agw1-pip1"
  location            = var.region
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
  domain_name_label   = "${var.env}-ag-frontend-ip"
  tags                = var.tag
}

resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "agw" {
  name                = "${var.env}-hub-agw1"
  location            = var.region
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
  enable_http2        = true
  tags                = var.tag
  sku {
    name     = "Standard_Small"
    tier     = "Standard"
    capacity = 1
  }

  gateway_ip_configuration {
    name      = "${var.env}-hub-agw1-ip-configuration"
    subnet_id = var.subnet_id
  }

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "${var.env}-frontend_ip_configuration_name-public"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.agw.id
  }

  frontend_port {
    name = "${var.env}-frontend_port_name-80"
    port = 80
  }

  frontend_port {
    name = "${var.env}-frontend_port_name-443"
    port = 443
  }

  backend_address_pool {
    name         = var.backend_pool
    ip_addresses = [var.vm_priv_address]
  }

  ssl_certificate {
    name                = var.cert_name
    data     = filebase64("certificate.pfx")
    password = "jrcszmnadminstrator@2021"
  }

  backend_http_settings {
    name                  = var.http_setting_name
    cookie_based_affinity = "Disabled"
    port                  = 80
    protocol              = "Http"
    request_timeout       = 1
  }
  http_listener {
    name                           = "${var.ag_listener_name}-http"
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = "${var.env}-frontend_ip_configuration_name-public"
    frontend_port_name             = "${var.env}-frontend_port_name-80"
    protocol                       = "Http"
  }

  http_listener {
    name                           = "${var.ag_listener_name}-https"
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = "${var.env}-frontend_ip_configuration_name-public"
    frontend_port_name             = "${var.env}-frontend_port_name-443"
    protocol                       = "Https"
    ssl_certificate_name           = "certificate"
  }

  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = "request_routing_rule_name-https"
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = "${var.ag_listener_name}-https"
    backend_address_pool_name  = var.backend_pool
    backend_http_settings_name = var.http_setting_name
  }
  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = "${var.request_routing_rule_name}-http"
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = "${var.ag_listener_name}-http"
    backend_address_pool_name  = var.backend_pool
    backend_http_settings_name = var.http_setting_name
  }
```

Comment: Deployment of APPGW takes 15-20 mins depending on the SKU. This is because of the underlying compute infrastructure that must be deployed alongside to support APPGW. Please do post with error in case of deployment failure.

Comment: which region are you deploying the resources to ? does it take more than 28 mins even you retry the deployment every time  or is it intermittent ?

Comment: can you please tell me , what azurerm version are you using ?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT for the first few deployment it took around 28-35min then after that its now taking around 15 min. I am using 2.90.0 azurerm version

Answer (score 0):

***Depending on the `App gateway sku` and other `configurations in the resource` , the creation time may `range from 15 min to 25 min` using Terraform azurerm Provider.***

Sometimes when ***using an old azurerm provider / terraform version*** might ***create some latency as they might be using old Azure API's*** which will result in the creation time taking a bit long than usual. ***Or If there is an ongoing issue on `Azure Resource Manager` then at that time too we may face issues like timeouts/ latency in creating or updating a resource which will be intermittent and later resolved from Azure side.***

**So, Its recommended to use the latest Terraform version and latest azurerm provider to avoid such issues.**

**I used your code to create the application and it took normal time to complete the creation as below :**

[image]